# Modify URL components in Python 2

Tags: python, url, python-2.x, urlparse

Is there a cleaner way to modify some parts of a URL in Python 2?

For example

```
http://foo/bar -> http://foo/yah
```

At present, I'm doing this:

```
import urlparse

url = 'http://foo/bar'

# Modify path component of URL from 'bar' to 'yah'
# Use nasty convert-to-list hack due to urlparse.ParseResult being immutable
parts = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))
parts[2] = 'yah'

url = urlparse.urlunparse(parts)
```

Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'clean'?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately, the documentation is out of date; the results produced by `urlparse.urlparse()` (and `urlparse.urlsplit()`) use a [`collections.namedtuple()`-produced class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) as a base.

Don't turn this namedtuple into a list, but make use of the utility method provided for just this task:

```
parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)
parts = parts._replace(path='yah')

url = parts.geturl()
```

The [`namedtuple._replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) lets you create a new copy with specific elements replaced. The [`ParseResult.geturl()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.ParseResult.geturl) then re-joins the parts into a url for you.

Demo:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://foo/bar'
>>> parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> parts = parts._replace(path='yah')
>>> parts.geturl()
'http://foo/yah'
```

[mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) filed a [bug report (with patch)](http://bugs.python.org/issue21746) to address the documentation issue.

Comment: I was going to point this out.  The utility methods are provided to `urlparse.ParseResult` by the subclass returned by `namedtuple`.  I think that this should be pointed out in the 2.7 docs, because without knowing that, you have no way of knowing that `_replace` actually _is_ part of the public API for this class...

Comment: Even more interesting is the mention of [`BaseResult`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.BaseResult) in the docs which doesn't appear in the source at all ... (sorry about the digression ... It's late ... +1 anyway)

Comment: @mgilson: heh, indeed, that must be a leftover from before `namedtuple` was used.

Comment: Thanks - that's a nicer solution.  Although, as pointed out in the other comments, there seems to be no way to know about it, based on the docs alone.

Comment: @GarethStockwell: yeah, looks like a doc bug; none filed yet, I'll do that later.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- [Ninja'd](http://bugs.python.org/issue21746) you on the doc bug

Comment: @mgilson: \o/ less work for me! :-P Can I push you to add a decent example to the docs as well, along the lines of what I did in this answer?

Comment: Whoa there buddy, lets not get carried away now.  an _example?!?!_  Who's gonna use that :-)

Comment: Sadly, this does not allow setting attributes that are not always available. For example, the `username` and `password` attribute, which are only in the result tuple when they were part of the URL that was parsed.

Comment: @TimVisée: those extra attributes are *derived values*. They are part of the netloc value; use `_replace()` to set a `netloc` string that includes the login info: `parts._replace(netloc='{}:{}@{}'.format(newusername, newpassword, parts.netloc.rpartition('@')[-1]))`

Answer (score -1):

I guess the proper way to do it is this way.

As using `_replace` private methods or variables is not suggested.

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse

res = urlparse('http://www.goog.com:80/this/is/path/;param=paramval?q=val&foo=bar#hash')
l_res = list(res)
# this willhave ['http', 'www.goog.com:80', '/this/is/path/', 'param=paramval', 'q=val&foo=bar', 'hash']
l_res[2] = '/new/path'
urlunparse(l_res)
# outputs 'http://www.goog.com:80/new/path;param=paramval?q=val&foo=bar#hash'
```

Comment: it's part of the public interface, it's just prefixed with underscrore to not clash with actual members.