# Can't edit a URL with python

Tags: python

I am new to python and just wanted to know if this is possible:  I have scraped a url using `urllib` and want to edit different pages.

**Example**:
 `http://test.com/All/0.html`

I want the `0.html` to become `50.html` and then `100.html` and so on ...

Comment: Yes, changing the last part of the URL is possible.

Comment: thank but how do i go about it. ive tried url.split but cant seem to get it to change the correct part of url. or can i scrape all into one rather than one at a time

Comment: Just googled "python modify url", the first link was [Modify URL components in Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24200988/2301450). You can even use `str.rpartition` or `str.split`. If you have a *specific* problem with your code, include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
found_url = 'http://test.com/All/0.html'

base_url = 'http://test.com/All/'

for page_number in range(0,1050,50):
    url_to_fetch = "{0}{1}.html".format(base_url,page_number)
```

That should give you URLs from `0.html` to `1000.html`

If you want to use `urlparse`(as suggested in comments to your question):

```
import urlparse

found_url = 'http://test.com/All/0.html'
parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(found_url)
path_parts = parsed_url.path.split("/")

for page_number in range(0,1050,50):
    new_path = "{0}/{1}.html".format("/".join(path_parts[:-1]), page_number)
    parsed_url = parsed_url._replace(path= new_path)
    print parsed_url.geturl()
```

Executing this script would give you the following:

```
http://test.com/All/0.html
http://test.com/All/50.html
http://test.com/All/100.html
http://test.com/All/150.html
http://test.com/All/200.html
http://test.com/All/250.html
http://test.com/All/300.html
http://test.com/All/350.html
http://test.com/All/400.html
http://test.com/All/450.html
http://test.com/All/500.html
http://test.com/All/550.html
http://test.com/All/600.html
http://test.com/All/650.html
http://test.com/All/700.html
http://test.com/All/750.html
http://test.com/All/800.html
http://test.com/All/850.html
http://test.com/All/900.html
http://test.com/All/950.html
http://test.com/All/1000.html
```

Instead of printing in the for loop you can use the value of parsed_url.geturl() as per your need.  As mentioned, if you want to fetch the content of the page you can use python `requests` module in the following manner:

```
import requests

found_url = 'http://test.com/All/0.html'
parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(found_url)
path_parts = parsed_url.path.split("/")

for page_number in range(0,1050,50):
    new_path = "{0}/{1}.html".format("/".join(path_parts[:-1]), page_number)
    parsed_url = parsed_url._replace(path= new_path)
    # print parsed_url.geturl()
    url = parsed_url.geturl()
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(str(page_number)+'.html', 'w') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
    except Exception as e:
        print "Error scraping - " + url
        print e
```

This fetches the content from `http://test.com/All/0.html` till `http://test.com/All/1000.html` and saves the content of each URL into its own file.  The file name on disk would be the file name in URL - `0.html` to `1000.html`

Depending on the performance of the site you are trying to scrape from you might experience considerable time delays in running the script.  If performance is of importance, you can consider using [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)

Comment: thanks LearnerEarner work great but its counting backwards from 1000 and not forwards

Comment: silly me its not counting backwards it selecting last element in range i need it to step

Comment: parsed_url.geturl() is selecting last element i need it to step ie 50.html, 100.html ect.. up to 1000.html when button clicked

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "_selecting last element_") and "_button click_".  I updated my answer with the expected output of the script I gave in the answer. The particular parameters used in `range()` function in `for` statement are to stop 50 on each iteration.  Please provide more details of the issue you are facing.

Comment: There was a typo in my previous comment - Please read "The particular parameters used in range() function in for statement are to _stop_ 50 on each iteration." as "The particular parameters used in range() function in for statement are to _step_ 50 on each iteration."

Comment: i want it to scrape data from http://test.com/All/50.html save to a file then press enter and scrape http://test.com/All/100.html and save to different file and so on sorry if im been a little slim on answer but im new to python.. im thinking i need to convert the int to a list the get python to select next element in list when i click enter?? not sure if this make any sense at all

Comment: Updated the answer.  Instead of using _urllib_, I used _requests_ module.  Since, I do not have the complete picture of your scenario, I left out a few validations and else conditions to you. In my opinion your intention of writing a program should be to automate your task as much as possible.  So, forget about hitting enter for every page, which is near to impossible, say, if you are scarping a million URLs.

Comment: @SimonBrown You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted if you think my answer helped you in solving your problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?